# how to insert an admin tab in prestashop Back office?

Tags: prestashop

i would like to insert a new tab in the BO, i created the tab and its controller but i got the error *no controller found* here is my code:

```
  public function installTab($class_name, $name)  {
    $tab = new Tab();
    // Define the title of your tab that will be displayed in BO
    $tab->name[$this->context->language->id] = $name; 
    // Name of your admin controller 
    $tab->class_name = $class_name;
    // Id of the controller where the tab will be attached
    // If you want to attach it to the root, it will be id 0 (I'll explain it below)
    $tab->id_parent = 0;
    $tab->active = 1;
    // Name of your module, if you're not working in a module, just ignore it, it will be set to null in DB
    $tab->module = $this->name;
    // Other field like the position will be set to the last, if you want to put it to the top you'll have to modify the position fields directly in your DB
    return $tab->add();
```

}

```
public function install()
{
...
$this->installTab('AdminBarCodeGenerator', 'Scan des codes barre');
}
```

and my controller

```
class AdminBarCodeGeneratorController extends ModuleAdminController{

public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
}

public function display(){
$smarty = $this->context->smarty;
$scan_form=$this->renderForm();
$smarty->assign('scan_form',$scan_form);
 return $this->display(__FILE__, 'views/templates/admin/tabs/scan.tpl');
 }
}
```

[image]

and my controller class is under the path *controllers/admin/ AdminBarCodeGeneratorController.php*

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/Timezone-design/prestashop-module-icecat

You can find the answer in this repository.

Please change your controller file name as "AdminBarCodeGenerator.php".

Comment: i tried it but i got the same error controller not found